# Vanishing all files while mounting to windows using samba 14.04

Tags: mount, samba, permanent-delete

I am trying to mount windows share folder to a local folder in my Ubuntu 14.04 as part of a program. All files existing in the local folder vanished after mounting to windows using samba. All files copied after mounting are available in the windows share also and that part is fine.

My problem is "All files existing in the local folder vanished after mounting to windows using samba."

My command to mount is

```
rc = subprocess.call(["mount","-t","cifs", "-o",
                  "username="+smb_user+",password="+smb_pass,
                  "//"+smb_host+"/"+smb_target,
                  to_transport])
```

Comment: this is normal behavior, since mounting a partition to a folder makes the folder point to the mounted partition. you should mount the share to an empty folder.

Comment: I  understood this as the default behavior. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: do you want to be able to write to the original folder? while the samba share is mounted?

Comment: Not exactly, I just wanted to preserve the files which were there before mounting. So, I will be able to use the older files in the share after mounting. I don't want to copy to somewhere and then copy back as my files are of large size.

Comment: a bind mount will show the contents of both folders; however all writes will go to the samba and the original folder contents will not be seeable from the samba side.

Comment: But that will not help. My intention is to use them in samba (my understanding is windows share is what you meant by samba).